# Lengthy jQuery AJAX request freezes browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have an AJAX request, processing of AJAX request is complex and lengthy. The problem is that this lengthy request freezes browser. I mean when AJAX request is in process then no matter if I click any link/button from page or type some Url of same website in browser address bar it does nothing and keep waiting fro AJAX request response, once AJAX response arrives back other processes start working. I am using **async: true** with AJAX request.
Here is the code I am using. Its a simple page having nothing else but this jQuery AJAX request. My server side PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/doprocessing',
                async: true,
                success: function () {
                    alert('done');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Why this is happening? How can I solve this?

PS: Before you mark this duplicate, I have checked almost all similar questions on StackOverflow. No solution is working in my case (though solution in most cases was using **async: true** which I am already doing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Show the rest of your JavaScript file please.

Comment: What sort of process did you do on your ajax request target?

Comment: @EM-Creations I have updated post, now post having complete HTML of my page.

Comment: @Pratansyah Its send mails to different people (say 10 different people), its sending 10 separate mail and not using CC or BCC.

Comment: The body of the main page is populated from ajax target?
If so make sure that the functionalities of target page works before sending 10 emails

Comment: If I were you, I would check the ajax's target page itself first before blaming it on the ajax's process. Try using postman tool to simulate your ajax call

Comment: @BlessonChristy Main page? You mean the page whose HTML I have posted above? No, there is no body of page. Just an alert when response is returned from target (Ajax handler page). And Ajax handler (target) don't have any Html either. Its just sending mails (kind of controller you can say)

Comment: @Pratansyah Postman tool? Link please. Target (Ajax handler) is send mails only. No other functionality or Html there.

Comment: @MuhammadGulfam Try googling "Postman tool"

Comment: the problem most likely lies with the php code - why is it taking so long to process a request? Can the PHP process be simplified and made quicker?

Comment: Thank you everybody. Rauli Rajande's solution worked for me. I had to use session_write_close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, why any of the links of the same website are not working during ajax, is that your script is locking the session in the server.

You could either not to use session for this script, or finish session after you are sure that this is correct user etc, but before starting sending emails (or doing anything else lengthy).

Use [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before starting sending emails in PHP for this.

Alternatively you can implement your own asynchronous session handler.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Are there any limitations or concerns which I should keep in mind while using  session_write_close(). Will this have any affect on Session?

Comment: Yes, the $_SESSION is not available after this point in this script, but nothing else. There is another quite common reason for similar "server locking", which happens when you do too many requests at the same time to ajax (or video files) and your browser runs out of allowed sockets (6 for Chrome).

Comment: And if this doensnt work for someone?